# How to optimise a sql doublon checker

Tags: sql, mysql, duplicates

I would like to optimise my Doublon checker if anyone knows how it could be faster.

```
$doublonchecker="delete bad_rows.* from eMail as good_rows inner join eMail as bad_rows on bad_rows.EMAIL = good_rows.EMAIL and bad_rows.EMAIL_ID > good_rows.EMAIL_ID";
$resultdoublon = mysql_query($doublonchecker);
        if (!$resultdoublon) {
        die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do it the following way:

```
Delete from Email where ID not in 
(
Select Min(em.ID) minID
from eMail em  group by em.Email
)
```

Answer (score 2):

That query would use an index on `(EMAIL)` or on `(EMAIL, EMAIL_ID)`. However, you shouldn't have to run that query more than once, so its performance shouldn't worry you too much. Once you have removed your "Doublons" just replace the index on `(EMAIL)` with a `UNIQUE KEY` on `(EMAIL)` and you'll never have duplicate emails ever again.